# Inserting text after callback value is reached - Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to insert text to text widget in Tkinter after a certain value is reached from my scale widget. However, it seems like my if statement does not work and nothing is inserted into text widget after the calculate button is pressed.

```
self.dU = Scale(self.f2, from_=100, to=-100)
self.calculate_button = Button(self.f2, text="Calculate", command=self.calculate)

self.results_display = Text(self.f3, height=10, width=62)
self.results_display.pack()
self.results_display.configure(state=DISABLED)

def results_text(self):
    if self.dU.get() > 0:
        self.results_display.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.results_display.insert(END, "dU > 0, internal energy of the particles increases, therefore temperature increases.")
        self.results_display.configure(state=DISABLED)

def calculate(self):
    self.results_text()
```

Comment: You need to be a little bit more specific about what you were expecting to see and explain is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are performing the `if` statement about one millisecond after the scale is created.

If you want the `if` statement to be called whenever the value changes, configure the `command` parameter of the scale.

For example:

```
self.du = Scale(..., command=self.scale_changed)
...
def scale_changed(self, value):
    value = int(value)
    if value > 0:
        ...
```

Note: even though `self.du.get()` will return an integer in this case, the current value is passed to `scale_changed` as a string.

Comment: I edited my question, could you please review again. I want to add text to my text widget after the calculate button is pressed. In this case, when dU > 0, nothing is being inserted into the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement works, but you are only calling it once, when your program boots. I'm guessing you want to run that check every time the value of the slider changes. To do that you need to use a variable and put a trace on it:

```
    self.dU = tk.IntVar()
    self.dU.trace('w', self.check)
    s = tk.Scale(self, variable=self.dU, from_=100, to=-100)
    s.pack()

    self.results_display = tk.Text(self, height=10, width=62)
    self.results_display.pack()
    self.results_display.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

def check(self, *args):
    if self.dU.get() > 0:
        self.results_display.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.results_display.insert(tk.END, "dU > 0, internal energy of the particles increases, therefore temperature increases.")
        self.results_display.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```